# Strange text message

Tags: instant-messaging

[image]#tps#16#tpe# if you don't need time for error correction, #lks#click here#lke#. What is this??

Comment: Where are you seeing this? Is this a list of SMS messages or something else? It just looks like some badly composed spam.

Comment: Yes it qas in a sms message and today i got a text that just says status but it looks like i sent it to myself but the # it shows from is 111-3001. Is someone doing some type of ping test on me or what?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't click on ANY link from someone that I don't know.  You are asking for trouble!